# RecyclerView shrinks when keyboard opens

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have this recyclerview

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/serviceRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addNewServiceBtn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />
```

which has inside this

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/serviceSelectExpertRegisterContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:paddingVertical="5dp"
    >
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/serviceSelectExpertRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/serviceDescriptionExpertRegister"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/serviceSelectExpertRegisterContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
    android:hint="@string/service_description"
    android:background="@drawable/border_edit_text"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="top|start"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="3"
    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
    />
```

adn when I open my keyboard it shrinks as the images demonstrate
[this is the shrinked image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz1Al.jpg)

[this is not shrinked one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYJ6J.jpg)

I have tried android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" (and all the other windowSoftInputModes) but it still has the same reaction.

Is there any way to just make the layout go up and on affect anything.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing padding for recyelerview, it solves the issue for me

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33024603)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with your code but putting your recyclerview inside of scrollview might solve your problem. When keyboard opens screen will scroll and try to fit content to the the screen :

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addNewServiceBtn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"> 

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/serviceRecyclerView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

the quick fix of the solution will be to wrap the all Views of your layout.xml into ScrollView, then your views inside RecyclerView will not resize after keyboard close.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code in adapter Class on onBindViewHolder method

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

or

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

or
you can add this line in your onCreate

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Comment: As I mention on the question I have tried doing that and all other combinations but it still is not working, I am suposing it has to do with RecyclerView or with the fragment recyclerview is in